# Why isn't the Microsoft Update Catalog working?

Tags: windows, maintenance

The [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/) web site seems to be very unreliable.  If it isn't working, what troubleshooting steps are sometimes helpful?

(Please note that the Microsoft Update Catalog is not the same thing as Microsoft Update, although they offer the same content.  The Microsoft Update Catalog is a web site where you can download off-line installers, including installers for different versions of Windows than the one you are running.  It requires the use of Internet Explorer, and is surprisingly fragile.)

*Note: this is intended as a canonical question, to collect various possible solutions to the various common problems with the Microsoft Update Catalog.  I'm posting an initial answer, but additional answers are encouraged.  Posted to Server Fault rather than Super User because the MUC is primarily used by system administrators, end users will typically use Windows Update or Microsoft Update instead.*

Comment: @yagmoth555: it would be a good answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/q/683660/96662) though. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common problem is error 8DDD0010.

In my case, I was able to resolve this by logging into the built-in Administrator account (usually named Administrator and disabled by default) and turning on IE compatibility mode for microsoft.com.

Other reports suggest that these steps may help:

- Resetting Internet Explorer
- Adding the MUC web site to the trusted sites list
- Disabling popup blockers
- Downloading fewer updates at a time (less than 100)
- Creating a new local account (with admin privilege) and using that
- Trying again later (sometimes the problem is at the server end)

I also recommend using a machine with a direct internet connection rather than one that accesses the internet via a proxy server.  (Especially if the proxy server requires authentication.)

Answer (score 0):

i  found the below download works when the search for updates takes forever. 
best bet is download it, reboot then install it immediately you have rebooted

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135445

works almost every time

Comment: That is a fix for the Windows Update  / Microsoft Update client - I don't *think* it has any impact on the Microsoft Update Catalog, which uses a different ActiveX control.  (But it would be worth trying, if you don't already have it installed.)  Oh, but that particular update has been superseded, you should install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3161608 instead.